# How to add an image with transparency to a TDbgrid column in delphi?

Tags: image, delphi, transparent, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I am trying to add an image to a column on a TDbgrid that takes transparency into account.  When drawing the image from a TImageList on the canvas in the DBGridDrawColumnCell procedure, I need the background of the image (the same color as the pixel in the lower left corner) to take on transparency.  I want this transparency area to show the highlight color or non-highlight color, especially when themes are used, such as Aero.  I have been able to accomplish this in older versions of Windows with color values of clHighlight or clWindow as the background color.  But with Aero themes, it always paints a box behind the non-transparent part of the image instead of the gradient blue highlight color that Aero uses.  How can I accomplish this?

I believe I am supposed to use alpha channel but I'm not sure how to do this from a TImageList to a canvas.  I believe the cell is painted completely with the actual highlight color before I start drawing on the canvas in the cell.  I just want to draw the non-transparency part of the image and leave the background.

Comment: If Delphi still does not support PNG (with alpha-channel ability) images, there is good library [PNGComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127)

Comment: @Abelisto I tried your advice and loaded PNGComponents.  It has its own lmageList and I would get the same result with no transparent background.  I also found that Delphi 2009 + has a PNGImage library that can be added to the project if using png images.  I could not get it to work with this library either.  Finally, I was able to solve my problem.  See answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally determine how to display images on a dbgrid with transparency even if themes, such as Aero is used.

I used a regular TImageList and loaded the images that I needed to display on the dbgrid. In my case there were two and they were in icon (ico) format. Instead of transferring the image to a bitmap and then drawing it to the dbgrid canvas as most old code recommends, I simply used the following simple code in the DBGridDrawColumnCell procedure:

```
if DataCol=0 then
begin
     if (MApptsConflict.Value='<none>') then
         ImageIndex := 0
     else
         ImageIndex := 1;

     ImageList.Draw(TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas,Rect.Left+2,Rect.Top+2,ImageIndex,True);
end;
```

This will draw directly to the dbgrid canvas from the TImageList which will give the desired transparency.

UPDATE: I tried it with bmp's loaded in the Timagelist and it worked too.

Comment: Why would you transfer the image to a bitmap first?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz because that is the way my code did it before and most old code methods online taught you to do it this way.  For example, [at Delphi.About](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa032205a.htm).  Maybe the ImageList.Draw method was not available in earlier versions of Delphi.  But it definitely is the easier way to accomplish what I needed.